# ClassCastException in scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am getting ClassCastException when I try to type cast. Spark submit code is below.
Input line : "2017-02-25 14:39:09,123 For: PO1028,PD1028,Product PD1028 doesn't exist in SAP DB."

```
                        println("Print each sap rdd " + line.saplogMsg)                    
                                    if (line.saplogMsg.contains("For:")) {
                                      startTime = line.loggedat
                                      println("startTime : " + startTime)
                                      val customFields = line.saplogMsg.split(",");
                                      TransactionId = customFields(0).split(":")(1).trim()
                                      println("TransactionId : " + TransactionId)
                                      customField2 = customFields(1)
                                      println("customField2 : " + customField2)
                                      appln = "SAP"
                                      layer = "APP"
                                      errorMsg = line.saplogMsg.split(",")(2)
                                      println("errorMsg : " + errorMsg)
                                    }
    if (line.saplogMsg.contains("doesn't exist")) {
                                      endTime = line.loggedat
                                      println("endTime "+endTime)
                                      status = "failed"              
                                      val purchaseOrderOld:PurchaseOrder = mapPO.get(TransactionId).asInstanceOf[PurchaseOrder]
                                      println("SAP Transaction Id : " + purchaseOrderOld)     
                                  purchaseOrderOld.startTime = startTime
                                      purchaseOrderOld.TransactionId=TransactionId
                                      purchaseOrderOld.customField2=customField2
                                      purchaseOrderOld.application=appln
                                      purchaseOrderOld.layer=layer
                                      purchaseOrderOld.errorMsg=errorMsg
                                      purchaseOrderOld.endTime=endTime
                                      purchaseOrderOld.status=status
                                }
     package logMonitor                        
     case class PurchaseOrder(                        
                          var startTime: java.sql.Date,
                          var endTime: java.sql.Date,
                          var TransactionId: String,
                          var customField1: String,
                          var customField2: String,
                          var status: String,
                          var errorMsg: String,
                          var application: String,
                          var layer: String)
```

I am trying to frame a New Purchase Order object but retrieving old Purchase Order and updating the Purchase Order object in Map.
Output Console:
sap : 1
SapLogLine(2016-04-01,For: PO1000,PD1000,Product PD1000 doesn't exist in SAP DB.)
Print each sap rdd For: PO1000,PD1000,Product PD1000 doesn't exist in SAP DB.
startTime : 2016-04-01
TransactionId : PO1000
customField2 : PD1000
errorMsg : Product PD1000 doesn't exist in SAP DB.
endTime 2016-04-01
17/10/03 19:34:06 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1507039435000 ms.1
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.None$ cannot be cast to logMonitor.PurchaseOrder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming, `mapPO` is a `Map`. 
So, you have two problems here:

First, `mapPO.get` returns an `Option`, so, casting it to `PurchaseOrder` cannot work.

Second, in this particular case, there is no entry in the map matching your transaction id, so, it returns `None`.

You would avoid the whole class of problems like this, if you had `mapPO` type properly declared, and avoided runtime type casts.